# Recursive Geocoding in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, coordinates, geocoding

I am analyzing a relative big amount of coordinates in PHP within a `for` cycle and I make a reverse geocoding calling the following function:

```
function getLocation( $coordinates )
{
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' . trim($coordinates) . '&sensor=false';
    $json = @file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json);
    $status = $data->status;
    //print_r ( $data->results[ 0 ]);
    if ($status == "OK")
    {
        return $data->results[ 0 ]->address_components[ 1 ]->long_name . ", " . $data->results[ 0 ]->address_components[ 2 ]->long_name;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem arised is that quite often Google (logically) answers me back with a null json_array and I don't have the reverse geocoding of each coordinate.

how can I bypass this issue? Do you know any other service?
I saw many libraries to reverse geocode but I would prefer to use them as last resource in order not to make heavier my small project.

Comment: So you have a load of coodinates and are looking to get a name back for each?

Comment: Yes, you sticked to the point. I have a load of records and I want to show them in a table to the user with the reversed geocoding

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well google will normally give you a reason why it failed. I know from past experience that it will fail if you give it too many in a certain time so hence you need to put sleep(500) or something so you don't overload google.

The docs say that it has a tolerance - of perhaps it's giving you an address but those fields aren't populated. Some debug code would help here.

Equally there is some rules you can add e.g

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&location_type=ROOFTOP&result_type=street_address&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Would limit you results down and may give you a better address.

It's probably a good idea to store any addresses you have.